# fix the URL when the client moves from one page to another in a Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, html, css, url

is there any way to fix the URL in a Single Page application when the client moves from one page to an other,but the URL changes in background?
I tried to use @routeProvider but I think it's not my case :/
thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about [HTML5's History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), especially the [`.pushState()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method).

Check out the [browser coverage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), nowadays very wide, but that might need fallbacks, according to the old browsers you might want to support.